# EventKit. How can I get videoconference url from EKEvent

Tags: swift, eventkit, ekevent

I have an event that has a meet or zoom link. However, I can't find a way to get the link of type `https://meet.google.com/...`. An example:

```
let calendars = eventStore.calendars(for: .event)
var events: [EKEvent] = []
        
for calendar in calendars {
     let oneMonthAfter = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 30*24*3600)
     let predicate =  eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: Date(), end: oneMonthAfter, calendars: [calendar])
            
     let collection = eventStore.events(matching: predicate)
     events.append(contentsOf: collection)
}
        
let event = events.first! // This event has a meet link associated but I can't get the link
```

EventKit has a class named `EKVirtualConferenceURLDescriptor` (more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekvirtualconferenceurldescriptor?changes=l_1&language=objc)). However, the documentation isn't good and only talks about creating a new one, not how we can get it from an existing event.

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end?

Comment: After reading documentation, I have the feeling that Apple gives you the external event identifier. With that id, you have to use the API of each system (Zoom, Google Meet...) to get the link. I could not confirm this last statement.

Finally, I applied the parsing of the notes field for now. The service adds the event details in the notes field. This field includes the link to the video conference. It was enough for me.

Comment: thank you for sharing. I'm also looking at whether the location string has a url. In the end, seems like heuristics work for every service except FaceTime. Which is ironic. Did you find a way to extract FaceTime links, by any chance?

Comment: the same question about videoconference link.